# IFS Formula Not Working

Tags: google-sheets

I can't seem to get the following formula to work in my google sheet.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(Q2:Q=3,"1",Q2:Q=2,"0.8",Q2:Q=1,"0.6"))`

It is looking at a score column which is shown in the screengrab below but no matter what way I try the formula it gives me an N/A error instead of the correct number output.

[image]

I have tried both IF and IFS (currently shown in formula) and none of them seem to work.

EDIT:

[image]

Formula used to extract the number is as below:

`=ARRAYFORMULA((IF(K2:K="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(K2:K, "^\d")))))`

Comment: Note that **`"1"`** is a text string and **`1`** is an integer, therefore **`("1"=1)=FALSE`**  This may cause unexpected behavior in formulas.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Extract number strings as integers.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/LEFT(range,1))))
```

## Your Issue

I checked your formula and the problem is that you are extracting the numbers as strings (text) but the IFS conditions look for integers.

You could update IFS to search for number strings but it typically makes sense to store numbers as integers; more so if you intend to use them in further calculations.

If the original formula is adjusted to return integers, your IFS formula would work properly, however it's also written to return number strings. I recommend you update it so the value-if-true arguments return integers, eg. **`1, 0.8, 0.6`**, instead of strings, eg. **`"1", "0.8", "0.6"`**.

## Convert Number Strings to Integers

In Sheets, number strings can be coerced to integers by incorporating them in a mathematical operation.  For example:

```
=1<>"1"
=TRUE 

=1="1"*1
=TRUE
```

Testing if the first character  is a digit can be combined with converting the number strings to integers by dividing one by the inverse of the string:  **`1/(1/n)`**. This calculation will return **`n`** wherever **`n`** is a non-zero digit, and for everything else will trigger an error:

```
# AND(ISNUMBER(n), n<>0)
=1/(1/n)
=n

# ISTEXT(n)
=1/(1/n)
=#VALUE

# ISBLANK(n)
=1/(1/n)
=#DIV/0
```

## Formula to Return Integers

For any 2D or 3D range, this formula will return the first character of each value as an integer, if it's a non-zero digit, or IFERROR will return an empty value.

This example uses the 3D range `J2:L`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IFERROR(
     1/(1/LEFT(J2:L, 1))))
```

If you prefer, you could adapt your REGEXEXTRACT formula following the same approach as the formula above. The reason LEFT was used above is that it makes for a shorter formula.

Equivalent FORMULA using REGEXEXTRACT:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IFERROR(
     1/(1/REGEXEXTRACT(J2:L, "^.")))
```

## CHOOSE instead of IFS

You could completely replace IFS with CHOOSE using the range of integers as its index argument. I prefer this approach if additional conditions may be added or if the formula may be moved because the **`range`** is included once, whereas in IFS each individual condition requires its own **`range=n`**, which is repetitious.

For example, suppose the integers returned by the previous formula are in the range **`M2:O`**, the formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IFERROR(
     CHOOSE(
       M2:O, 0.6, 0.8, 1)))
```

## Combine "Formula to Return Integers" and CHOOSE

If useful, the two formulas can be combined into a single formula to eliminate the use of helper columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IFERROR(
     CHOOSE(
       1/(1/LEFT(J2:L, 1)), 
       0.6, 0.8, 1)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I've just tried out your formula and it works for me - are the values in column Q integers? The only thing I could find is if you've rounded in the column so it looks like it says 3 but is actually 3.1 or similar.

If so, you could modify your formula to use ">=" instead of just "="

Comment: I believe you are correct. I have edited the post above to include a screengrab of data and also formula used to extract the number. Is there a simpler way to do this? That was the only formula I could find to do it. Thank you.